# Eliminar el ultimo objeto de una pila hecha con un arreglo primitivo de tipo vector

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

quería pedirles su ayuda, actualmente estoy desarrollando una tarea sobre estructura de datos, más enfocada a realizar una cola y una pila, pero con arreglos primitivos como vectores.

Esta es mi clase Pila

```
public class Pila {

    private int indice;
    private int numeroRegistro = 0;

    public Pila() {

        indice = -1;
    }

    public int getIndice() {
        return indice;
    }

    public int getNumeroRegistro() {
        return numeroRegistro;
    }

    public Boolean push(Proveedor elemento) {
        if (indice < 100 - 1) {

            numeroRegistro++;
            elemento.setId(numeroRegistro);
            VectorPila.pila[++indice] = elemento;

            return true;

        } else {

            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return indice == -1;
    }

    public Proveedor[] pilaList() {

        return VectorPila.pila;
    }

    public Proveedor buscarProveedorId(int id) {

        for (int i = indice; i >= 0; i--) {

            Proveedor proveedor = VectorPila.pila[i];

            if (proveedor.getId() == id) {

                return proveedor;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    //debe borrarse solo era para identificar que los datos se almacenaran
    public void mostrarDatosPila() {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("La pila está vacía");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Datos en la pila:");

            for (int i = indice; i >= 0; i--) {
                Proveedor proveedor = VectorPila.pila[i];

                System.out.println("ID: " + proveedor.getId());
                System.out.println("Descripcion: " + proveedor.getDescripcion());

                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }

    public Pelicula[] vectorColaDePeliculas() {

        Pelicula[] peliculas = null;

        if (isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("La pila está vacía");
        } else {

            for (int i = indice; i >= 0; i--) {

                peliculas = VectorPila.pila[i].getCola();

            }

            return peliculas;
        }

        return peliculas;
    }

    public void MostrarPeliculasEnLaPila(JTextArea listaPeliculas) {

        listaPeliculas.setEditable(false);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        listaPeliculas.setText("");

        if (isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("La pila está vacía");
        } else {

            for (int i = indice; i >= 0; i--) {

                Proveedor proveedor = VectorPila.pila[i];
                Pelicula[] cola = proveedor.getCola();

                if (cola != null) {
//                    sb.append("---------------------------------------------").append("\n");
//                    sb.append("Proveedor ID: ").append(proveedor.getId()).append("\n");
//                    sb.append("Descripcion: ").append(proveedor.getDescripcion()).append("\n");
//                    sb.append("Películas en la cola: ").append(proveedor.getDescripcion()).append("\n");

                    for (Pelicula pelicula : cola) {

                        if (pelicula != null) {

                            sb.append("---------------------------------------------").append("\n");
                            sb.append("ID: ").append(pelicula.getDni()).append("\n");
                            sb.append("Nombre: ").append(pelicula.getNombre()).append("\n\n");
                            sb.append("Categoria: ").append(pelicula.getCategoria()).append("\n\n");
                            sb.append("Audiencia: ").append(pelicula.getAudiencia()).append("\n\n");
                            sb.append("Formato: ").append(pelicula.getFormato()).append("\n\n");
                            sb.append("---------------------------------------------").append("\n");
                        }

                    }

                    listaPeliculas.setText(sb.toString());
                }
            }

        }
    }

    public void eliminarUltimoElemento() {
        if (isEmpty()) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se ha encontrado ningún registro agregado");

        } else {
            Proveedor proveedor = null;

            proveedor = VectorPila.pila[numeroRegistro - 1];
            
            

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, proveedor.getDescripcion());

            Pelicula[] peliculas = proveedor.getCola();

            if (peliculas[0] != null) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La pila contiene registros de Peliculas");

            } else {

                VectorPila.pila[numeroRegistro - 1] = null;
                indice--;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se ha eliminado el último registro de la pila");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**El vectorPila tiene 100 posiciones**

El problema está en el método eliminarUltimoElemento()

**No se me elimina correctamente el último Elemento de la Pila, ya que las pilas siguen ese principio del primero en entrar el último en salir técnicamente me toca borrar a la última.**

Yo creo que lo estoy haciendo bien ya que la idea es usar el índice o el numeroRegistros para saber cuántos registros tiene la pila y posteriormente hacer -1 para borrar solo el ultimo, **y al correrlo borro bien el primero pero cuando borro un segundo se genera este error**

Lo que no entiendo es que tiene que ver mi clase con esto.

por aquello aqui esta la clase.

Este es otr error que me aparece Realmente es el importante
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public class Proveedor {

    private int id;
    private String descripcion;
    private Pelicula[] cola;

    public Proveedor() {
    }

    public Proveedor(int id, String descripcion) {
        this.id = id;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
        this.cola = new Pelicula[100];
    }

    public Pelicula[] getCola() {
        return cola;
    }

    public void setCola(Pelicula[] cola) {
        this.cola = cola;
    }
   
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }

    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripción;
    }

}
```

Esta es otra Clase donde tengo el arreglo primitivo

```
public class VectorPila {
    
     public static Proveedor[]  pila = new Proveedor[100];
}
```

El problema está en que no borra el último elemento bien, si agrego muchos proveedores borra el primero cuando debe borrar el ultimo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hay cosillas que corregir, intento basado en:

A) solo se puede borrar un proveedor, si no tiene películas.
B) solo se puede borrar el último.

```
public void eliminarUltimoElemento() {
   if( isEmpty() ) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "No se ha encontrado ningún registro agregado" );
   }
   else {

         // inicialización innecesaria cambiamos.  
         // Proveedor proveedor = null;
         // proveedor = pila[ numeroRegistro - 1 ];
      Proveedor proveedor = pila[ numeroRegistro - 1 ];
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, proveedor.getDescripcion() );
      Pelicula[] peliculas = proveedor.getCola();

         // agregamos clausula para evitar que arroje error ante falta de array de peliculas
      if( peliculas != null && peliculas[ 0 ] != null ) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "La pila contiene registros de Peliculas" );
      }
      else {
         pila[ numeroRegistro - 1 ] = null;
         indice--;
            // disminuimos para que en la próxima llamada, elimine corectamente
         numeroRegistro--;
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Se ha eliminado el último registro de la pila" );
      }

   }
}
```

Para probar el código, cree esta clase:

```
public class Mi {

   void run() {
      Dni dn1 = new Dni( 10 );
      Dni dn2 = new Dni( 10 );
      Dni dn3 = new Dni( 10 );
      Dni dn4 = new Dni( 10 );
      Pelicula u1 = new Pelicula( dn1, 15, "vd", "a2", "su1" );
      Pelicula u2 = new Pelicula( dn2, 15, "vd", "a1", "su2" );
      Pelicula u3 = new Pelicula( dn3, 15, "vd", "a0", "su3" );
      Pelicula u4 = new Pelicula( dn4, 15, "vd", "a45", "su4" );
      Pelicula pelis1[] = { u1, u2 };
      Pelicula pelis2[] = { u3, u4 };
      Proveedor pro1 = new Proveedor( 1, "pelisA" );
      Proveedor pro2 = new Proveedor( 2, "pelisB" );
      Proveedor pro3 = new Proveedor( );
      pro1.setCola( pelis1 );
      pro2.setCola( pelis2 );
      Pila pi = new Pila();
      pi.push( pro1 );
      pi.push( pro2 );
      pi.push( pro3 );
      pi.mostrarDatosPila(  );
      pi.eliminarUltimoElemento();
      pi.mostrarDatosPila(  );
   }

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      Mi mi = new Mi();
      mi.run();
   }
}
```

Comentarios:

La clase **VectorPila** me parece que no es necesaria, yo la reemplacé, agregando el atributo **public static Proveedor[] pila = new Proveedor[ 100 ];** en la clase **Pila**.

En **Proveedor** tenemos:

```
public Proveedor( int id, String descripcion ) {
    this.id = id;
    this.descripcion = descripcion;

       // this.cola = new Pelicula[100];
       // el this, se usa cuando hay conflictos de nombres o cuando se ha de pasar 
       // como argumento, por lo que en la siguiente linea, es innecesario.
    cola = new Pelicula[100];
}
```

Espero haber interpretado bien tu problema.

Agrego la clase **Pila** para que veas como implementé el array

```
public class Pila {

   private int indice;
   private int numeroRegistro = 0;
   public static Proveedor[] pila = new Proveedor[ 100 ];

   public Pila() {
      indice = -1;
   }

   public Boolean push( Proveedor elemento ) {
      if( indice < 100 - 1 ) {
         numeroRegistro++;
         elemento.setId( numeroRegistro );
         pila[ ++indice ] = elemento;
         return true;
      }
      else {
         return false;
      }
   }

public void eliminarUltimoElemento() {
   if( isEmpty() ) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "No se ha encontrado ningún registro agregado" );
   }
   else {
      Proveedor proveedor = null;
      proveedor = pila[ numeroRegistro - 1 ];
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, proveedor.getDescripcion() );
      Pelicula[] peliculas = proveedor.getCola();
      if( peliculas != null && peliculas[ 0 ] != null ) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "La pila contiene registros de Peliculas" );
      }
      else {
         pila[ numeroRegistro - 1 ] = null;
         indice--;
         numeroRegistro--;
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Se ha eliminado el último registro de la pila" );
      }

   }
}

   public Proveedor buscarProveedorId( int id ) {
      for( int i = indice; i >= 0; i-- ) {
         Proveedor proveedor = pila[ i ];
         if( proveedor.getId() == id ) {
            return proveedor;
         }
      }
      return null;
   }

   //debe borrarse solo era para identificar que los datos se almacenaran
   public void mostrarDatosPila() {
      if( isEmpty() ) {
         System.out.println( "La pila está vacía" );
      }
      else {
         System.out.println( "Datos en la pila:" );
         for( int i = indice; i >= 0; i-- ) {
            Proveedor proveedor = pila[ i ];
            System.out.println( "ID: " + proveedor.getId() );
            System.out.println( "Descripcion: " + proveedor.getDescripcion() );
            System.out.println();
         }
      }
   }

   public Pelicula[] vectorColaDePeliculas() {
      Pelicula[] peliculas = null;
      if( isEmpty() ) {
         System.out.println( "La pila está vacía" );
      }
      else {
         for( int i = indice; i >= 0; i-- ) {
            peliculas = pila[ i ].getCola();
         }
         return peliculas;
      }
      return peliculas;
   }

   public void MostrarPeliculasEnLaPila( JTextArea listaPeliculas ) {
      listaPeliculas.setEditable( false );
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      listaPeliculas.setText( "" );
      if( isEmpty() ) {
         System.out.println( "La pila está vacía" );
      }
      else {
         for( int i = indice; i >= 0; i-- ) {
            Proveedor proveedor = pila[ i ];
            Pelicula[] cola = proveedor.getCola();
            if( cola != null ) {
//                    sb.append("---------------------------------------------").append("\n");
//                    sb.append("Proveedor ID: ").append(proveedor.getId()).append("\n");
//                    sb.append("Descripcion: ").append(proveedor.getDescripcion()).append("\n");
//                    sb.append("Películas en la cola: ").append(proveedor.getDescripcion()).append("\n");

               for( Pelicula pelicula : cola ) {
                  if( pelicula != null ) {
                     sb.append( "---------------------------------------------" ).append( "\n" );
                     sb.append( "ID: " ).append( pelicula.getDni() ).append( "\n" );
                     sb.append( "Nombre: " ).append( pelicula.getNombre() ).append( "\n\n" );
                     sb.append( "Categoria: " ).append( pelicula.getCategoria() ).append( "\n\n" );
                     sb.append( "Audiencia: " ).append( pelicula.getAudiencia() ).append( "\n\n" );
                     sb.append( "Formato: " ).append( pelicula.getFormato() ).append( "\n\n" );
                     sb.append( "---------------------------------------------" ).append( "\n" );
                  }
               }
               listaPeliculas.setText( sb.toString() );
            }
         }

      }
   }

   public boolean isEmpty() {
      return indice == -1;
   }

   public Proveedor[] pilaList() {
      return pila;
   }

   public int getIndice() {
      return indice;
   }

   public int getNumeroRegistro() {
      return numeroRegistro;
   }
}
```

Como puedes ver, solo agregué **public static Proveedor[] pila = new Proveedor[ 100 ];** como atributo, y cambié las llamadas de **VectorPila.pila[ xx ]** por **pila[ xx ]**.

Comment: gracias, oye te molestaría enseñarme como hiciste eso ultimo que mencionas lo de meter el vectorPila dentro de la clase pila mejor? es que yo lo tenía así y me daba error ,entonces quería ver como lo habías echo

Comment: waw,  si me funciono de maravilla tu método muchas gracias de verdad de corazón, sinceramente ya solo eso me faltaba de mi proyecto y no sabía cómo solucionarlo, muchas gracias de verdad.

Comment: Un placer ayudarte!!

Answer (score 0):

Si mantenes un `numero de registro`, estas rompiendo el invariante de la estructura de datos.
Que es VectorPila? Donde lo incializas? Que es VectorPila.pila? Si tenes una clase pila, todas las estructuras de datos que uses en la clase deberian estar definida EN la clase.

Lo unico que tenes que definir dentro de la clase son los metodos de la estructura

```
vacia    :: Pila a
apila    :: a -> Pila a -> Pila a
cima     :: Pila a -> a
desapila :: Pila a -> Pila a
esVacia  :: Pila a -> Bool
```

Entonces tu abstraccion deberia ir de Vector -> Pila (con las funciones de arriba) -> Pila Pelicula (o como quieras ponerle)

Esta ultima clase deberia tener tus metodos propios del negocio como MostrarPeliculasEnLaPila, buscarProveedorById, etc

Fijate que haciendo esta abstraccion en el medio, Eliminar el ultimo elemento se vuelve trivial porque solo vas a tener que llamar al desapilar.

Se entiende? Desmodulariza un poco el codigo y vas a ver que sale facil. Si necesitas ayuda para la implementacion de la Pila avisa.

Saludos!

Comment: sinceramente entiendo el punto pero no sé cómo implementarlo en el código

Comment: bueno allí ya pase el código del vector pila

Comment: es solo un vector de 100 posiciones

Comment: Ok, alli dentro de ese mismo codigo empeza a implementar las funciones.

Ejemplo:
'''
 private final int TAMANIO_MAXIMO = 100;
    private Object[] elementos;
    private int tamanio;

    public Pila() {
        elementos = new Object[TAMANIO_MAXIMO];
        tamanio = 0;
    }
public boolean esVacia() {
        return tamanio == 0;
    }
}
'''

Comment: Perdon por el formato.

Comment: @leandroian los comentarios son efímeros. Ese código debe ir como edición a tu respuesta.

Comment: si la verdad no entiendo tu respuesta.